# Mirror changes to side of cube across all six sides

Tags: modeling, mesh, workflow

I want to create a cube with some general extrusions. This should be the same across all sides of the cube. Is there a way to make this mirrored across all six sides? I know that I could delete the rest of the cube, copy my changes, rotate it 90°, move it down and to the side, and repeat for all the sides, then remove doubles, but I'm wondering if there's a way to make this work in real time.

In the below image, all six sides should copy the changes shown here on the one side:

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

## Modifiers:

You could do this with a [*Mirror modifier*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Mirror) and an [*Array Modifier*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Array#Array_Modifier):

1. Delete the excess geometry:

   [image]
2. Add a Mirror modifier:

   [image]
3. Add an *Array Modifier*.
4. Add an *Empty* rotated `-90°, 0°, 90°` (assuming the mirror is mirroring along the `X` axis):

   [image]
5. Set the empty as the [*Object offset*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modifiers/Generate/Array#Options) in the array modifier:

   [image]

Result:

[image]

## Duplifaces:

Another way is with [*Duplifaces*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Duplication/DupliFaces):

1. Add a cube and a plane.
2. *Parent* the plane to the cube (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>):

   [image]
3. With the cube selected, enable *Duplifaces* in the *Properties Editor > Object > Duplication*:

   [image]
4. Edit the plane object:

   [image]

The duplifaces will be displayed in object mode:

[image]

## Limitations:

- The array modifier method will not rotate the duplicated faces in the same direction: (this is tweak-able by adjusting the rotation of the empty)

  [image]
- Duplifaces do not display in edit mode.

Answer (score 8):

- You could select all faces in edit mode <kbd>A</kbd>
- Inset  <kbd>I</kbd> with individual option  <kbd>I</kbd>

[image]

- Invert selection <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>I</kbd>
- Extrude with <kbd>E</kbd> with individual origins

[image]

This way you only need to repeat the rotation for all faces.

Comment: If you set the transform orientation to *Normal* you can do the rotation all at once too.

Comment: This is exactly the kind of workflow I was looking for. The rotation probably isn't even that important, but I just included it in my example to make the side more interesting.

Comment: @Keavon The rotating issue has been solved by gandalf3  see http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5060/how-can-faces-be-rotated-around-their-individual-normals