# How can faces be rotated around their individual normals?

Tags: modeling, transforms, normals

In edit mode with these settings:

- Face selection
- Pivot point: individual origins
- Transformation orientation: Normal

The faces don't rotate around the normals, is there another required setting that I overlooked?

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to press a key to specify the axis. (i.e. <kbd>X</kbd>, <kbd>Y</kbd> or <kbd>Z</kbd>)

Setting the [*Transform orientation*](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Transform_Orientations) aligns the `XYZ` coordinates to something, e.g.:

- *Global* aligns the axes to the world
- *Local* aligns the axes to the selected object(s) rotation
- *Normal* aligns the axes to the selected element(s) normal

etc.

Note that pressing the axis key once always snaps to the *Global* orientation, regardless of the setting in *3D view > Header*. To use the orientation specified in *3D view > Header*, press the axis key twice. (e.g. <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>)

With your settings, (*Individual origins*, *Normal*, *Face*) to rotate each face around its normal we should rotate around the `Z`, see the [wiki](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/3D_interaction/Transform_Control/Transform_Orientations#Normal):

> The z-axis of the manipulator will match the normal vector of the selected [element]

So by pressing <kbd>R</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>:

[image]

Answer (score 6):

Yes you can do this, *all accessible from interface but included keys*

1. Enter Editmode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)
2. Change to face-editing (<kbd>3</kbd>)
3. Select all (<kbd>A</kbd>)
4. Mesh -> Edges -> Edge Split (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>E</kbd>, <kbd>D</kbd>)
5. Change orientation to normal (<kbd>,</kbd>, <kbd>2</kbd>)
6. Change pivot to individual origins (<kbd>.</kbd>,<kbd>2</kbd>)
7. Rotate about the Z axis `(<kbd>R</kbd>, <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd>) ... move mouse:

[image]

Comment: how would I do this in python?

Comment: That should be a separate question.

Comment: I have the answer :D

Answer (score 1):

```
#python to rotate all faces 

#rotate all faces on mesh by 1 degree
import bpy, bmesh,math
from mathutils import Matrix
bm = bmesh.new()
bm.from_mesh(bpy.data.objects['Cube'].data)
for face in bm.faces:
        
            
    axis = face.normal
    rot = Matrix.Rotation(math.radians(1) , 4, axis)
    cen = face.calc_center_bounds()
    mat = bpy.data.objects['Cube'].matrix_basis
    bmesh.ops.rotate(bm, cent=cen, matrix=rot, verts=face.verts,space = mat)
    
bm.to_mesh(bpy.data.objects['Cube'].data)
bm.free()
```