# Blender can't get extrude to lock in odd position again

Tags: modeling, transforms, edit-mode

So I was making a side walk for a curved park of a road that I made, but I wasn't sure how I was going to make it. when I tried to extruded the edge, the extruder locked into place in some odd angle, but it was an angle that surprisingly worked perfectly for me so I got the side walk on on side of the road but on the other side I couldn't figure out how to get the extruder to lock into place. I will include a picture to help show my problem. I would really like if someone could point out how I made the extruder lock into place like in a odd angle.

Thanks, Nova

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default extrude will lock along the *normal* of the selected faces. The normal is perpendicular to the plane of the face. In other words, the direction the face is facing.

- To unlock it, press <kbd>Z</kbd> after extruding.
- To re-lock it, set the *transform orientation* to *normal* in the *header* of the 3D view. Then press <kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> after extruding and unlocking (or <kbd>G</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> if you cancelled/completed the extrude/transform operator)

  [image]

Also see:

- [Extrude Faces along Local Normals](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/7365/599)
- [How can faces be rotated around their individual normals?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/5060/599)