# Modify multiple objects at the same time (f.ex.: 8)

Tags: objects, edit-mode

I'm still pretty new to blender but I was wondering if there was a function in Blender to  make the exact same changes to 8 or more objects which are on different positions later on.

For example. You have a room with 12 Pillars and you want to apply the same changes to those objects. How would one do this without making changes to one pillar and then have to copy paste the pillars to that exact same location over and over for each change.

Thank you in advance for any help or nodge into the right direction. I can give you picture to show my situation later if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Objects can have the same object data.

[image]

[image]

It introduces some constraints. Like if you what to have different materials for those objects, the materials should be linked to the object, not to the object data.

[image]

Comment: @Merlin The first thing I did was learning Alt + D and the effect it gives. How can reading the manual, which I did years after using the shortcut, be easier? >95% new questions here can be answered by googling, including this one. But for someone who just wants a quick answer, it is as difficult as reading the manual.

Comment: @unwave Thank you so much. i will give it a try as soon as I am home so I can give it a try. Showing me that it is possible was great but including the shortcuts and keys pressed is even better. I mean I did some research beforehand but with all my attempts I came to the same threats and couldn't find anything as helpful as this. Would be great to have someone like you to help me with my other problem in such an awesome way.

Comment: @Merlin No, I think dumping a GIF as an answer does make a good answer for anything that's based on visual interaction.

Comment: @unwave what [SE] defines as a good answer is obviously different.  I hope you understand that I was trying to encourage a sense of quality, remembering that quite often, the results on google often point back to here.

Comment: @VarmintLP Here is an answer as well https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/10499/how-to-change-mutiple-parts-by-changing-just-one

Comment: @unwave sorry for the delay but I basically forgot to do it yesterday evening and when I remembered I was just too tired to try. :C
But now I can say fulheartedly: Thank you. Thank you for this short and easy to understand responds and thank you for the effort you have put into this. You are awesome. :)
I do hope that this will also help others to solve their issue. ;)
Also thank you for the link to the array modifier. I will surely have a look into this.