# How to mirror an object in a 90 degree angle?

Tags: modeling, mesh

So, I'm building a TARDIS...

I'm working on the details off the side, and want to then mirror it to the other side(the one adjacent to the one already detailed), so I don't need to do the door two times.
How can I do this?

Comment: Related: [Mirror changes to side of cube across all six sides](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/5057/mirror-changes-to-side-of-cube-across-all-six-sides?rq=1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to use an array modifier to rotate it 90 degrees, then mirror it along the X and Y axis:

[image: array]

Result:

[image: result]

Comment: Should the array look like this?http://imgur.com/FEY7zzB,HOPHwLj#1     And there's a problem... The sides don't merge... As shown here : http://imgur.com/FEY7zzB,HOPHwLj

Comment: After posting that, I tried something and it worked. So, you need to scale the empty, by minus one (-1), along the x axis. And the rotate it by -90 degrees, along the z axis. Then increment the Merge Distance, on the array, to 0,04.

Comment: @someonewithpc looks like you solved it, but just make sure to set the merge distance in the array modifier.